# How to focus on a test in truffle

Tags: truffle, unittesting

In JasmineJS and other Unit testing frameworks, there is usually a focus feature which works like this `using fit`:

```
fit('Crowdsale contract - vault works correctly', function(done){
});
```

if I want to skip the test I'd use `xit` 
Is there a way in truffle to do it? (Focus and skip tests)

Comment: according to mocha, I should be able to do it `it.only()`